# Creating measure with several outcomes

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

I created this table:

[image]

It shows on which day of the month and at which time of the day (always grouped to 15 minute steps so we have 96 times per day) how many connection points are active. As data (in table 'Usage') I have the start and the end time of the connection ([ConnectionStart Time], [ConnectionEnd Time]) so when a connection starts at 00:00 and ends at 00:50 it has to count for the groups 00:00, 00:15, 00:30 and 00:45 since the connection is active all the time in between (obviously).

And this is what my problem is: I have to manually calculate that it counts for all the times included.
I tried this measure and I get not errors but somehow it won't show the right values:

```
TimesOverlapping = 
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS ( 'Usage' );
    FILTER (
        'Usage';
        'Usage'[ConnectionStart Time] < ( 'Usage'[ConnectionStart Time (groups)] + TIME ( 0; 14; 59 ) )
        && 'Usage'[ConnectionEnd Time] > 'Usage'[ConnectionStart Time (groups)]
    )
)
```

Is it even possible to create a measure that counts 96 times for every day of a month how many connection points are active on this particulare moment?

Comment: How does your table with the connection starts and end times look like?

Comment: I have one column with the ChargingPoint ID, one with the date, one with the start time and one with the end time. And I just realized that the groups which I created ([ConnectionStart Time (groups)]) also automatically got integrated as its own column. This is the reason my measure didn't work.

Comment: What I expected: The grouped times are integrated only in my visualization-table and not in the data table itself so power bi would take one row out of the data table (with ChargingPoint ID, start time and end time) and validate if all 96 times of every day of the visualization table are within the start and the end time from this one row of the data table. So kind of like a loop.